# Trouble Shooting IIS 8.5 Classic ASP Loading Time

Tags: iis-7, sql-server-2000, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

So I am migrating a server and can't find out why the new machine / environment is slower than the old one. Here are the facts.

Old Machine
2008 R2 - 3.1ghz quad core Xeon w/ 12gb
SQL2k \ SQL 2008
IIS 7

New Machine
2012 R2 - 2.5ghz 8 core Opteron w/ 16gb
SQL2k \ SQL 2008 \ SQL 2016
IIS 8.5

So here is what I have done. I migrated the codebase onto the new machine. I loaded up SQL2k which I know is not supported and I plan to upgrade. The same page on both machines loads fine. Old machine loads in 10 seconds new machine takes 124 seconds.

Next step was to convert database from 2k to 2016 via 2008. Done with that same load speed 124 seconds. Next changed connections strings from OLEDB to Native 11. That dropped the load time from 124 down to 30 seconds.

Next I went into query manager and ran the SP on both machines. Old machine takes 4 seconds to complete the query. New machine takes less than 2 seconds to run the same query on sql2k but on sql2016 the same query runs in under a second. I then wrote a much more intensive query and ran it on both machines. The old machine took 120 seconds to execute the new machine took 12 seconds in 2016 and about 25 seconds in SQL2k.

So at this point I am assuming it is IIS settings. Next I went to the old machine installed SQL 2016 and loaded it up to test speeds with the new database running on the old server with IIS 7. Zero difference.

I have tried connection string changes with IP vs NAME no difference.

Is there some change in IIS 8.5 that affects classic ASP performance or a setting in 2012R2 that I am missing somewhere? All app pools and sites are exactly the same on both machines.

Any help would be great, thanks

** Added all sql settings are the same also for both sql2k and sql2016 along with IIS settings. Firewall settings also the same. .NET environments all the same too.

** Changed New Machine is 8 Core not 4

Answer (score 0):

Too many cores man.

Some questions - it's this all one site?  All one app pool?

Classic asp wasn't written for 8 core machines.  In IIS 8.5 there are settings you can set for processor affinity and numa node (memory) affinity.  But really only useful if you have separate sites or app pools to run.  But before looking at any of that I'd ask you to try an experiment.  Make a vm version of your site, set to use 4 cores and 8 gb ram.  Deploy two copies to your machine.  Test hitting the page in one of them.  You may get better performance.  You could also try this without vms by setting the site to run in two worker processes (web garden configuration) and bind each process to half the cores.

Answer (score 0):

Just try adding a host file entry IP pointing to the machine name. I understand you are running SQL server in the same machine but still it will make a big difference from my experience.

As @Brain suggested, Web gardens will help a little on high load but I think your issue is just related to the connection speed.